# Photodiode arrays: how can different wavelengths be compared?

Tags: photodiode, detector

In DAD (diode array detector), aka PDA (photodiode array) detectors, the light is dispersed and different wavelengths fall onto different diodes. This allows finding out which wavelengths were present in the beam and what the intensity of each of them was.

Different wavelengths carry different energies, so when "blue" light falls onto the 1st diode and "red" light falls onto the last one, the amount of current generated should be different (due to quantum efficiency) even if the number of photons was the same. Moreover [it seems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photodiode) like we may need different materials for different diodes.

When looking at the spectrum, I assume lower values correspond to lower intensities. How is this reconciled? Do these detectors have some multiplication factor "hardcoded" for different diodes, and maybe different materials, too?

Comment: Surely the signals can be amplified. By different factors too.

Comment: Please edit your question to spell out acronyms, so those of us who aren't in your industry know what DAD/PDA detectors are.  The answers to your questions in the last paragraph are probably both "yes", BTW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But when looking at the spectrum, I assume lower values correspond to lower intensity. So how is this reconciled?

Calibration.

Basically you need to measure the response of your photodiodes with an input of known intensity at different wavelengths, and determine the responsivity at each wavelength. Then when you measure an unknown source you can use the calibration data to correct the measurement and get the actual intensity (or spectral density) at each wavelength.

If you bought an instrument from a well-known vendor, they have probably done this in the factory and designed their firmware or software to apply the correction automatically to every measurement. For maximum accuracy, you might be required to test a reference sample periodically to update the calibration and allow for drift due to component aging.

> But different wavelengths carry different energy, so when "blue" light falls onto 1st diode and "red" light falls onto the last one - the amount of current generated should be different (due to quantum efficiency) even if number of photons was the same.

I'm not sure if you're misunderstanding something basic here, or just didn't word this clearly.

The photons of different wavelengths carry different energy, so at the same optical intensity, you will certainly have different photon flux density. You might also have varying quantum efficiency to complicate matters, but it's fundamental to have varying responsivity over wavelength, even if the quantum efficiency is constant. You may also have different efficiency of the intermediate optics delivering the beam to the photodiodes depending on wavelength.

In the end, you end up needing to calibrate the system, and that takes care of all these effects without needing to distinguish which particular effect causes the variability in responsivity.